# How to filter simple products by size?

Tags: attributes, filter, magento-1.14

I'm new to magento and I have some troubles. I've managed to filter products by style or color, which are configurable products, but I can't figure out how to filter by size, where products are simple products.

Here's the code I use for style and color:

```
    if (isset($_GET['style'])) {
        $this->addAttributeToFilter('style', array('eq' => $_GET['style']));


    if (isset($_GET['solid'])) {
         $this->addAttributeToFilter('solid', array('eq' => $_GET['solid']));
     }
```

I get attributute name and ID from URL. My filter show styles and color only if they are available for products inside the filtered category, but it always show all sizes and when I try to filter any of them, nothing is returned. Also, there is a problem when I select for example more than 1 style to filter. I should get 2 products with two styles, but instead I get only one (first one).

Comment: $this is your product collection?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: Your question is not clear as sometimes you says color, size and somewhere you saying solid and style? What do you want to filter exactly?

Comment: I want to filter sizes. Colors (attribute name "solid") and styles works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code instead of yours:

```
$this->addAttributeToSelect('size');

if (isset($_GET['style'])) {
    $this->addAttributeToFilter('style', array('eq' => $_GET['style']));
}

if (isset($_GET['solid'])) {
     $this->addAttributeToFilter('solid', array('eq' => $_GET['solid']));
}

if (isset($_GET['size'])) {
     $this->addAttributeToFilter('size', array('eq' => $_GET['solid']));
}
```

If you want to filter the attributes by multiple options then you can try the below code:

```
$this->addAttributeToFilter('my_attribute_code', array('in' => array(12,10))); // 12, 10 is option ids
```

Comment: I already tried this method. Doesn't work. Works for configurable products, but not for simple products.

Comment: Did you check if your simple products have the correct options selected?

Comment: Yes. Every simple product has a size attribute with selected size.